# How to set CSS property when developing for the Vodafone MWP?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, html, widget

I'm working on a widget for the Vodafone Mobile Widget Platform and was trying to change some properties of a DIV using JS. I used

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').style="width: 10px; height: 10px"";
```

I should work, but it doesn't seem to set the right values. Is the widget run-time treating these statements differently than normal?

Comment: Is there an extra double quote at the end in your actual code, or is that a copy and paste error?

Answer (score 0):

The runtime shouldn't be the issue. Within the runtime (S60 and Android) a Opera browswer rendering engine is used and it is the same core as it is used on the desktop version. 
Did you try the Android version from the developer platofrm (http://developer.vodafone.com)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for posting. This is not exactly an answer, please have a look at [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).